# How to use to functions - MAX(smthng) and after COUNT(MAX(smthng)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand why I can't use this in my code :

```
SELECT MAX(SMTHNG), COUNT(MAX(SMTHNG)) 
FROM SomeTable;
```

Searched for an answer but didn't find it in documentation about these aggregate functions.

Also I get an SQL-compiler error "Invalid column name "SMTHNG"".

Comment: Where did you find that query? Do you know that query's purpose? Do you know that that query cannot run? Or If that's the query you write, then what is your purpose when writing it? Could you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: update your question  and add a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. (you code is not clear tome)

Comment: Imagine, a `COUNT(MAX(SMTHNG)) ` will return `1`, because `MAX` function returns the highest value for `SMTHNG` field ;) So, this statement has no sense.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? Your query is incomplete

Comment: Ok, Ok i understand that i can't use 2 aggregate functions in one string in 'first select'.

Comment: A quiz is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please read my comment.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the statement have to be changed.

If you want to count the highest values in `SMTHNG` field, you may try this:

```
SELECT T1.SMTHNG, COUNT(T1.SMTHNG) 
FROM SomeTable T1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(SMTHNG) AS A
        FROM SomeTable
    ) T2 ON T1.SMTHNG = T2.A
GROUP BY T1.SMTHNG;
```

Comment: Super! So, please, accept my answer as a solution (and up-vote, if you wish).

Comment: Ups, no - where is a problem what i can't understand - i try to output MAx(salary*months) and COUNT it if its equal 2 or more LIKE MAx(salary*months) = 1-st - 100500, and 2-en 100500 so COUNT(MAX(salry*months) = 2.

Comment: That is another problem, which haven't been expressed in original question. All you need to do is to count months with the highest salary ;) You can achieve that by changing inner join. Note, that i do not see your data and can't read in your mind or direct from your screen.

Comment: My English is bad so i write short one - i understand what i need not to code few Aggregate functions in one statesment, so i look how it do enother people and realize my own. TY for ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know what the maximum SMTHNG in the table is with:

```
SELECT MAX(SMTHNG) FROM SomeTable;
```

This is an aggregation without `GROUP BY` and hence results in one single row containing the maximum SMTHNG.

Now you also want to know how often this SMTHNG occurs and you add `COUNT(MAX(SMTHNG))`. This, however, does not work, because you can not aggregate an aggregate directly.

This doesn't work either:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(max_smthng), COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT MAX(smthng) AS max_smthng FROM sometable) t;
```

because the sub query only contains one row, so it's too late to count.

So, either use a sub query and select from the table again:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(smthng), COUNT(*)
FROM sometable
WHERE smthng = (SELECT MAX(smthng) FROM sometable);
```

Or count per SMTHNG before looking for the maximum. Here is how to get the counts:

```
SELECT smthng, COUNT(*) 
FROM sometable
GROUP BY smthng;
```

And the easiest way to get the maximum from this result is:

```
SELECT TOP(1) smthng, COUNT(*) 
FROM sometable
GROUP BY smthng
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

use cte like below or subquery

```
with cte as
(
select count(*) as cnt ,col from table_name
group by col
) select max(cnt) from cte
```

you can not use double aggregate function at a time on same column

Comment: Sorry, but i think you misunderstood the question. Please, see my answer.